# How to keep the text near the footer if there is no content on the web page other then a single heading

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to keep my h1 to stay near the footer without using margin-bottom on the header so that my text will stay near the footer 
I want something like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A29Xj.png)

The solution I've tried is by giving margin-bottom:515px to header so that it will stay at bottom but it'll be appreciated if i get to know any better approach to achieve this thing

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: In order for someone to help you, please upload a snippet of code. Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cannot recommend absolute position due to overlapping issue. Flex would do the magic.

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  align-items: flex-end;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  height: calc(100vh - 100px);
}

h1 {
  margin: 0 0 50px;
}

.footer {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>H1 goes here</h1>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  <p>footer goes here</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use absolute positioning for h1:

```
position: absolute;
left: 0px; 
bottom: 0px;
```

Or make some divs to hold structure of your page:

```
//css
#header {
     height: 'headerHeight'px;
}
#content {
     height: Calc(100% - 'headerHeight'px - 'footerHeight'px);
}
#footer {
     height: 'footerHeight'px;
}
//html
<body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id "footer">your H1</div>
</body>
```